# PHP & MySql: can't update database

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I'm working on a project where I need to set the boolean value isHere to true(1)
when it finds the corresponding ID. However I can't seem to update the database. I can select from the database though.

I have two problems. First:

```
$handle = @fopen("../smartriders.txt", "r");

    if ($handle) 
        {
        while (($smartRider = fgets($handle, 255)) !== false) 
        { 

            if($update = $conn->query("UPDATE members SET isHere = 1 WHERE SmartRiderID = ?", $smartRider))
            {
                print("update successful");
            }
        }
        if (!feof($handle)) {
            echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
```

This yields a warning:

> Warning: mysqli::query() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given in index.ph on line 14.

line 14:

```
if($update = $conn->query("UPDATE members SET isHere = 1 WHERE SmartRiderID = ?", $smartRider))
```

the second problem: 
Even if I manually type the smartRider that is in the database, nothing gets updated.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: `expects integer`. Do you understand what it means?

Comment: And refer to mysqli_query manual. Passing your value to `query()` doesn't mean it will be added to your query.

Comment: Yes, I do, what I don't understand is why it says that, because SmartRiderID is  a VarChar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you refer to [`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) manual - you will see that second argument of this function is `int $resultmode`.

See - it is `int`. And it's purpose is to define a structure of returned result. So, passing your `$smartRider` to `query()` is **useless**.

`query` function **doesn't work** with prepared statements.

For prepared statements is [`prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php):

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE members SET isHere = 1 WHERE SmartRiderID = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $smartRider);
$res = $stmt->execute();
```

For cheking result of `execute()` see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php.

Comment: Thank you. I was used to David Malan's Harvard's CS50x library, which allows what I did. I incorrectly assumed it would work without it.

Answer (score -1):

problem1: Warning: mysqli::query() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given in index.ph on line 14.

solution:

```
if($update = $conn->query("UPDATE members SET isHere = 1 WHERE SmartRiderID = " . $smartRider))
```

Comment: This is insecure. Add whatever to your `smartRider` and have a nice sql-injection.